# Error #92: Identifier-List Parameters May Only Be Used In A Function Definition

Tags: c

I am attempting to compile some code, but am running into some problems that I cannot seem to figure out. Originally, I had three errors, but I have narrowed it down to one that I cannot seem to solve. There are three files I am working with right now: voltcon.c, mss_ace.c, and mss_ace.h. I have pasted the relevant code below:

Within mss_ace.c

```
    void ACE_init( void )
    {
    /* Initialize driver's internal data. */
        ace_init_flags();

    /* Initialize the data structures used by conversion functions. */
    ace_init_convert();
    }

    void ACE_configure_sdd
    (
sdd_id_t            sdd_id,
sdd_resolution_t    resolution,
    uint8_t             mode,
    sdd_update_method_t sync_update
    )
    {
    ...
    }
```

Within mss_ace.h

```
    typedef enum
    {
        SDD0_OUT = 0,    /*!< Analog Module 0 Sigma Delta DAC */
        SDD1_OUT = 1,    /*!< Analog Module 1 Sigma Delta DAC */
        SDD2_OUT = 2,    /*!< Analog Module 2 Sigma Delta DAC */
        NB_OF_SDD = 3
    } sdd_id_t;

    typedef enum
    {
        SDD_8_BITS = 0,
        SDD_16_BITS = 4,
        SDD_24_BITS = 8
    } sdd_resolution_t;

    #define SDD_CURRENT_MODE    1
    #define SDD_VOLTAGE_MODE    0
    #define SDD_RETURN_TO_ZERO  0
    #define SDD_NON_RTZ         2

    typedef enum
    {
        INDIVIDUAL_UPDATE = 0,
        SYNC_UPDATE = 1
    } sdd_update_method_t;

    void ACE_init(void);

    void ACE_configure_sdd(sdd_id_t sdd_id, sdd_resolution_t resolution, uint8_t mode, sdd_update_method_t sync_update);
```

Within voltcon.c

```
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "../../N3V2_hardware/biarri/firmware/drivers/mss_ace/mss_ace.h"

    sdd_id_t this_sdd_id = SDD0_OUT;
    sdd_resolution_t this_sdd_resolution = SDD_16_BITS;
    uint8_t this_mode = SDD_VOLTAGE_MODE;
    sdd_update_method_t this_sdd_update_method = INDIVIDUAL_UPDATE;

    void ACE_init();

    void ACE_configure_sdd(this_sdd_id, this_sdd_resolution, this_mode, this_sdd_update_method);
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

> voltcon.c: error: #92: identifier-list parameters may only be used in a function definition

What this error says to me is that it probably has to do with the third argument to my function.

---Update---
The error is caused by the last line in the code (the void ACE_configure_sdd one). My apologies on that. The #92 is just a code, it doesn't refer to the actual lines of code.

Comment: Could you please point out line 92 (which the error is about)?

Comment: The last line of `voltcon.c` doesn't make any sense; it looks like a function declaration, except you have *variables* rather than *types* in the argument positions.  You certainly can't *call* a function there, because you're not already inside a function.

Comment: Most of my programming experience is in MATLAB, so I am having a bit of difficulty with C. Oli, I understand what you are saying, what I am trying to do is call the function with a particular set of arguments. My understanding is that the function declaration in mss_ace.c tells us we have a function called ACE_configure_sdd that returns void, and that requires four input arguments (of the types specified). What I want to do is call this function with the inputs it asks for.

Comment: Whoops, I totally forgot that. The IDE I usually use adds all the stuff I need whenever I create a new file, but I am in a different environment now and I simply forgot that I needed to create a main function or something to that effect. Should be able to fix it easily now. Thanks!

Comment: @JosephGauthier: Unlike in Matlab, in C you cannot call functions unless you are already inside a function.  So `int main(void) { ACE_configure_sdd(this_sdd_id, this_sdd_resolution, this_mode, this_sdd_update_method); }` would probably be fine, for instance.

Comment: Yep, that worked. To make myself feel less stupid, I did fix it before you typed that. :-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the declaration of `ACE_configure_sdd` from `voltcon.c`. As it is already there in `mss_ace.h`.

It seems you are trying to call `ACE_configure_sdd` from `voltcon.c` but in `c` you can only call a function from inside of another function.

You can try doing this in `voltcon.c` :

```
void func1()
{
ACE_configure_sdd(this_sdd_id, this_sdd_resolution, this_mode, this_sdd_update_method);
}
```

now func1 can be called from some other function in your code or main() itself.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The last line within voltcon.c seems to be declaration of the function ACE_configure_sdd, but it's lack of type declarations of its variables. This is why the error "error: #92" came out.