# Macro for function declaration not working

Tags: c, macros, keil

I want to use a macro in order to easily change a function declaration, here is what I have for now :

```
#define MYDECLARATION(name)   void name (void)
```

When I call MYDECLARATION(my_thread); I get an error:

> identifier-list paramters may only be used in a function definition.

I tried to use ## like that :

```
#define MYDECLARATION(name)   void  ##name (void)
```

but I am pretty sure I will get : `voidmythread (void)` in my code. Do you have any idea on how to do it ?

I am also interested if you know some nice tutorials about macros in general.

---

In response to bitmask comment :

I am using KEIL compiler then my thread are working as follow :

```
 #define MYDECLARATION(name)   __task void name(void)
```

My call :

```
 MYDECLARATION(Mythread);
```

My definition :

```
__task void Mythread(void)
{
  //...
}
```

New test :

```
#define RET_TEST     __task void
#define PARAMETER    void

 RET_TEST MYDECLARATION(PARAMETER);
```

This is working... So I guess it's the fact to use a macro parameter into a function name which is not working...

Comment: What do you want to easily change about the function declaration? What its arguments are? Its return type? Its calling convention? ...?

Comment: Are you missing a semicolon at the end of the macro?  Try `#define MYDECLARATION(name)   void name (void);`

Comment: My aim it's to get a generic code between 2 different architecture. My problem is the syntax of the thread declaration.

Comment: The semicolon will be added when I gonna use the MACRO : MYDECLARATION(my_thread);  (I just added it in the topic)

Comment: The error must be somewhere else. Probably you are not showing what causes you trouble. My suspicion would be that you have a space between `MYDECLARATION` and `(name)`.

Comment: [Works like a charm](http://ideone.com/gbb1XO). You're not telling us something relevant. Show us the actual problem.

Comment: @JensGustedt No, there is no space.

Comment: @bitmask I have updated with more info.

Comment: Does the compiler error actually contain `paramters`? Or did you write it by memory?

Comment: If you write the last declaration (`__task void Mythread(void) { /* ... */ }`) without a macro, does the compiler still complain, or does it work ok?

Comment: Probably there's nothing wrong with the macro but..See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115795/error-92-identifier-list-parameters-may-only-be-used-in-a-function-definition).

Comment: Then it's `keil` specific because (apart from the `__task` thing) it's perfectly valid C.

Comment: Is __task a precompiler macro? And if so, does the pre compiler you are using do multiple passes? If not, the __task macro may not be getting run.

Comment: `gcc` has an `-E` option to output the preprocessed code. Maybe you can do the same with `keil`. Then you can figure out what the preprocessor produces from your code.

Comment: One more edit in my post with more tests...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand the pre-processing output is to use the -E option of gcc.

Apparently, I copied your program.

```
#define MYDECLARATION(name)    void name (void)

#include "stdio.h"


void my_thread()
{
  printf("hello world\r\n");    
    
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  MYDECLARATION(my_thread);
  return 0;
}
```

Now,
$gcc -E example.c

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  void my_thread (void);
  return 0;
}
```

You know, you can't call the function like that. It should be called as my_thread();
I did a change in your macro -  #define MYDECLARATION(name)    name()
It works fine. Hope this helps you.